# How do I pass multiple parameters to AWS SSM send_command with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have created a custom AWS SSM document for use with Run Command, I am then trying to use Boto 3 in order to send that command to a single EC2 instance.

The document require 2 parameters to be sent to it but I cannot figure out how to correctly do this by looking at the docs here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command

I can use the CLI successfully with this command:

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "ResetVpnMfa" \
    --document-version "1" \
    --targets '[{"Key":"InstanceIds","Values":["i-abcabcab"]}]' \
    --parameters '{"command":["GoogleAuthlock"],"username":["some.user"]}' \
    --timeout-seconds 30 \
    --region eu-west-1
```

My Python code:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='eu-west-1')

params={
    'command': ['GoogleAuthLock'],
    'username': ['some.user'],
}

response = client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=['i-abcabcab'],
    DocumentName='ResetVpnMfa',
    DocumentVersion='1',
    TimeoutSeconds=30,
    Comment='VPN MFA reset for some.user via Boto',
    Parameters=params
)
```

I get the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameters: An error occurred (InvalidParameters) when calling the SendCommand operation:
```

The SSM Document itself:

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Unlock or reset MFA on OpenVPN"
parameters:
  username:
    type: "String"
    description: "VPN user e.g. digger.dachshund"
  command:
    type: "String"
    description: "Command to unlock or reset MFA on OpenVPN."
    allowedValues:
    - GoogleAuthlock
    - GoogleAuthRegen
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  name: "VPNResetMFA"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - "/usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli --user {{username}} --lock 0 {{command}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a mismatch between your SSM document and the python code. You’ve misspelled `GoogleAuthlock` as `GoogleAuthLock`.  Parameters variables is such,

```
params={
'command': ['GoogleAuthlock'],
'username': ['some.user'],
```

}

Comment: Doh, how embarrassing, I could've sworn and cut 'n' paste that and had even tried different permutations.  This worked though, many thanks.