# create SSM document with boto3 that shuts down microservices and their associated EC2 instances

Tags: python, yaml, boto3, aws-ssm

I have been assigned a task to develop a solution that shut down all microservice processes running on a given EC2 instance in parallel and then shut down the EC2 instance itself and do this on a set of EC2 instances in parallel.  This is supposed to take input from a YAML configuration file (let's call it the parent) similar to the following that identifies the mount point of the micro services:

```
fabric: usprod1
sequence:
  stateless:
    - admin-portal
    - dashboard
    - haraka
    - vm-prometheus
    - watchtower-server
    - web-analytics-service
  dbclusters:
    - kafka
    - druid
    - rabbitmq
  zkclusters:
    - zookeeper
  shared:
    - eureka
  bootstrap:
    - consul
    - census
```

My solution is supposed to create "child" SSM documents that correspond to each mount point within a service group where there might be multiple EC2 instances associated with each mount point.  I've reviewed the following web pages, but they don't give me any insight as to how I'm supposed to use the parent YAML file to generate the children:

[How do I pass multiple parameters to AWS SSM send_command with Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678230/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-to-aws-ssm-send-command-with-boto3)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/create-ssm-document-api.html

Answer (score 0):

This case can be tackled using few approaches but I would suggest do some reading on Lambda or [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc) first and then you should be good to go.

Comment: I didn't specify this in my original question, but I need to be able to create the "children" SSM documents in Python in parallel by service group, execute them in parallel, and then delete them.  This python solution needs to use the "parent" YAML file as input to set the service groups.  I don't understand how Lambda or Step Functions would work here.